# Can I reduce this condition a & b & ( (!c && d) || !d)?

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

So, I want to check for `!c` only if `d` is `true`, but if `d` is `false`, just ignore `c`

Comment: Have you tried `d && !c`? With the"usual" short-circuit evaluation of C-like languages that will "ignore" (not evaluate) `!c` if `d` is not true. If you *don't* have a language which does short-circuit evaluation of logical operators then you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Basically it evaluates to `a & b & (!c || !d || !d)` You can find this out by building a small evaluation table of c and d with all possible values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But in that case, if d is false, it will evaluate the whole expression to false, and that's not what i want

Comment: Honestly, that's not really part of the question *body*. The title should be a quick and short summary of the problem you have, while the main question (including, if possible, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) should be in the question body. And of course you should include  expected results as well. Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Oh and please read about [the XY problem too](http://xyproblem.info/). Many people here don't really like questions which asks for help to a solution to an unknown problem. Including *why* you want to do what you do is always a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this:

`a & b & (!d || !c)`

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense

Comment: Using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) `(!d || !c)` is equal to `!(d && c)`, which is one less character to write for the lazy. :)